# GitHub notification about organisation events on specific URL?

Tags: php, github, notifications, github-api

Is there any way to get notifications about GitHub organisation events on some URL instead of checking notificactions with cron?

Comment: I don't think your question should be closed, but you should show more effort and diligence/background. Provide some references. You'll get better results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not natively. The GitHub [Notifications API](http://developer.github.com/v3/activity/notifications/) does not provide a way to work with notifications in a "push" model, so the best you can do is pull them every so often with cron.

I am also not aware of any third-party services that would automate the task of pushing notifications by hitting a custom URL every time a new notification is pulled from GitHub, even though it would be moderately easy to make such a service.